# Is there a function for extracting the first N elements of a vector in C++ (using the Eigen library)?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am wondering whether there is a function in the Eigen C++ library to extract the first N elements of a vector (i.e. a matrix with 1 column or 1 row)

In R there is the head() function - e.g. x = head(y, 5) would extract the first 5 elements of the vector y. I am looking for the Eigen equivalent.

At the moment I am just creating a vector of the required size using a loop to fill in the elements, but I figure using a built-in function - if one exists - might (hopefully) be faster.

Thanks

Comment: Took a brief look at the Eigen docs and the Tutorials on [Slicing and Indexing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) as well as on [Block Operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) might be useful.

Comment: If `y` is also a vector, then simply `x = y.head(N)` (most of the time there is no need to actually make a copy). If `y` was a matrix, you first need to [`reshape()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshape.html). Something like this should work: `y.reshape().head(N)`

Comment: If you are familiar with Matlab syntax, this may be helpful: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt

Comment: Do you just need the `N` first elements, or you want to loop over the first element and get `N` elements starting at arbitrary locations?